# How to dynamically change the string from the i/o stream in c

Tags: c

I was looking at a problem in K&R (Exercise 1-18), which asked to remove any trailing blanks or tabs. That pushed me to think about text messengers like Whatsapp. The thing is lets say I am writing a word *Parochial*, then the moment I had just written *paro*, it shows *parochial* as options, I click on that replaces the entire word (even if the spelling is wrong written by me, it replaces when I chose an option).

What I am thinking is the pointer goes back to the starting of the word or say that with start of every new word when I am writing, the pointer gets fixed to the 1st letter & if I choose some option it replaces that entire word in the stream (don't know if I'm thinking in the right direction).

I can use **getchar()** to point at the next letter but how do I:

1: Go backward from the current position of the pointer pointing the stream?
(By using **fseek()**)?

2: How to fix a pointer a position in an I/o stream, so that I can fix it at the beginning of a new word.

Please tell me my approach is correct or understanding of some different concept is needed. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard streams are mainly for going forward*, minimizing the number of IO system calls, and for avoiding the need to keep large files in memory at once.

A GUI app is likely to want to keep all of its display output in memory, and when you have the whole thing in memory, going back and forth is just a simple mater of incrementing and decrementing pointers or indices.

*(random seeks aren't always optimal and they limit you from doing IO on nonseekable files such as pipes or sockets)

Comment: So it happens when we are about to display the data (just when it resides in memory) not in stream?

Comment: @infinite counter question: why would you want to put the text into a stream before the user presses enter?